# Variable format changed to ~class.attribute in docs

Tags: python, python-sphinx, sphinx-napoleon

So I've been working on some docs for some weeks now and they always appeared fine until last night all the variables started coming up in the format `~Class.Attribute`. I attempted to rollback to multiple previous versions that had been working but they all show the Variables like this. Is there something I'm missing to get these to only show the attribute name without the `~Class.`.

```py
class Certification(TMDbObj):
    """ Represents a single Certification.

        Attributes:
            certification (str): Certification text.
            meaning (str): Certification meaning.
            order (int): Certification Order.
    """
```

[image: screenshot of documentation]

Comment: Can you reproduce this with code that does not involve `tmdbapis` (I don't know what that is)? A [mcve] would make it easier to help.

Comment: tmdbapis is the custom module im making that this documentation is for and this is happening to every object in the module

[Docs](https://testtmdb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the Sphinx napoleon extension it was reported in [issue #10181](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/10181) and will be fixed in the next Sphinx 4.5.0 release.

It happens for variables that aren't prefixed in the docstring with the class name or `cls` or `self`.